# Vue.js $refs are undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out why my Vue instance's **refs** are undefined.

## Using View.js from Laravel Project

Here you can see I instigate the Vue instance

**(resources\assets\js\app.js)**:

```
import AutoPopulateSelect from './components/results-text/AutoPopulateSelect.vue';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { 'auto-populate-select': AutoPopulateSelect }
});
```

And this is where I actually use the component with the **ref** on it

**(resources\views\results-text\edit.blade.php):**

```
<auto-populate-select ref="models">Vehicle Models</auto-populate-select>
```

I have tried running `app.$refs` however this just returns `undefined`. I have done this from within the console so the application would of finished loading.

## Edit:

Just noticed something string, if I run `console.log(app.$refs);` below where `app` is defined, so:

```
import AutoPopulateSelect from './components/results-text/AutoPopulateSelect.vue';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { 'auto-populate-select': AutoPopulateSelect }
});
console.log(app.$refs);
```

Then the **ref** is there! It appears to be when I attempt to do this from the console... does Laravel do something funky!?

Comment: Works for me: https://codepen.io/AndriusRimkus/pen/JawENW.
As Shawn has said, more code is needed, cause there's no issue with the code you provided.

Comment: @AndriusRimkus See update

Comment: you could do a quick test to make sure you are dealing with the same `app`. `console.log(window.app === app);` Or be explicit with the `app` exposure and do something like: `window.appWhyNotWork = new Vue`.

Answer (score 2):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#ref

> An important note about the ref registration timing: because the refs
> themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot
> access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet! $refs is
> also non-reactive, therefore you should not attempt to use it in
> templates for data-binding.

Where do you use `$refs`? Can you show your full code?

For your updated code, I agree with Andrius Rimkus. You should check the `app` you were using carefully, or just run `console.log(app)` in console after the page is loaded to see what the `app` object it is.

And, since you are using Vue, most code inside Vue you can just use `this` instead of `app`.

Comment: See original post: I have tried running app.$refs however this just returns undefined. I have done this from within the console so the application would of finished loading.

Comment: Can you show your code or make a minimal app for test?

Comment: Kinda hard to do this, as i'm using Vue.js from within a Laravel installation, is this helps? I will add the file names as to where my code is from above.

Answer (score 0):

I know this too late, but to anyone who is having this same issue,

`const app` has to declared globally, which fixed the issue for me.

So it should be:

```js
const window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'auto-populate-select': AutoPopulateSelect
  }
});
```

Now `console.log(app.$refs);` should display all the refs from other js files or inline functions.

Comment: I don't know where you tested that code, but declaring a `const window.app` is a syntax error. The `window` is already an object, so you just want to declare the `app` property on it, you can't make that into a constant.